# Get the corresponding non-empty adjacent cell in a column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, worksheet-function

I'm trying to find the formula for column "C" in order to obtain this:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | flower | **blue** |
| 2 |  | water | blue |
| 3 |  | sky | blue |
| 4 | green | grass | green |
| 5 |  | frog | green |
| 6 | yellow | lemon | yellow |
| 7 |  | sun | yellow |

I've tried with `INDEX` and `MATCH` but I haven't found yet the way to go.

*Bonus: a unique formula with ARRAYFORMULA would be very nice for my use case.*

Answer (score 2):

Given the exact layout and ranges shown in your post, delete everything from Col C and place this array formula in C1:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="",,VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A),FILTER({ROW(A:A),A:A},A:A<>""),2,TRUE)))`

This will lookup each row number for rows where Col B is not empty within a virtual array of only those row numbers where Col A is not empty paired with the value of Col A, and return the result from the second column of that array. Because the final parameter of `VLOOKUP` is `TRUE`, any exact row number searched and not present in the limited virtual array will "fall backward" to the last row number that was occupied.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this

```
=ArrayFormula(if(row(A1:A) <= max(if(not(isblank(B1:B)), row(A1:A))),vlookup(row(A1:A),filter({row(A1:A),A1:A},len(A1:A)),2),))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
=ArrayFormula(if(B2:B="",,lookup(row(A2:A),row(A2:A)/if(A2:A<>"",1,0),A2:A)))
```